# vba - запуск selenium chromedriver на разных ПК

Tags: selenium, vba, chromedriver

Качаю SeleniumBasic вот от сюда - https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases

На моем ПК работает в норме, а на других ошибка `Unknown error: unrecognized chrome version`

Пробовал устанавливать разные версии SeleniumBase но не помогает

Это кусок кода, на строке `.Start "chrome"` появляется данная ошибка

```
Dim sel As New Selenium.WebDriver

With sel 
        .AddArgument "--headless"
        .Start "chrome"
        .Get "http://domain.com"
End With
```

Comment: какая версия хрома на вашем ПК и на других?

Comment: Версии одинаковые Version 72.0.3626.121 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: а версии бейсика тоже одинаковые всегда?

Comment: Да, одинаковые... Сейчас нашел странный баг - если я закомментирую строку  .AddArgument "--headless" - то появляется окно хрома, сразу же закрывается и ошибка SessionNotCreatedError: session not created error from unkhown error: runtime.ExceptionContextCreated has invalid 'context'

Comment: Также, selenium в ошибке пишет что версия chromedriver=2.21.

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос заменив в ручную версию chromedriver на свежую, по адресу `C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\SeleniumBasic\chromedriver.exe`